# What is the meaning of "confluent''?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of the word *confluent* in the context of the phrase *the confluent of the river*?

Comment: Well, not much.  But "confluence of rivers" would mean the point where they join.

Comment: Baseball announcers who came into Pittsburgh used to describe the site of Three Rivers Stadium as at the confluence of the Allegheny and Monongahela Rivers, where they formed the Ohio.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=confluent&submit.x=0&submit.y=0

con·flu·ent  (kŏnfl-ənt)
Share:
adj.
1. Flowing together; blended into one.
2. Merging or running together so as to form a mass, as sores in a rash.
n.
1. One of two or more confluent streams.
2. A tributary.